# Fuel System Diagnostics

Tags: fuel-system

If I have a fuel system problem, I'm wondering what I'd need to do to be able to fix the issue. I don't want to be replacing parts just to see if it would now work. I'd rather take diagnostic steps to get to a solution rather waste a bunch and possibly never get to a solution. To that end:

**What are the steps involved to diagnose the fuel system with an electric fuel pump?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recently replaced the electric fuel pump in my Camaro. The fuel pump came with a sheet which has a diagnostic tree on it. Here are the steps involved:

[image]

Comment: What a lucky coincidence you bought that particular fuel pump because ... it has your answer in a handy flow chart. That is wonderful. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: If it turns out that the fuel pump itself is bad, it might have worn itself out trying to push fuel through a clogged fuel filter. Also, the fuel pump may have clogged the filter with bits of metal while it was dying, so I change the filter every time I change a pump.